# Don't break a line on '-'

Tags: c#, cpu-word, aspose

[image: line breaks]

The content betweent '-' seems to be one row, if it's too large it will wrap,how to address this?

Comment: if you want a meaningful answer try to formulate a clear and coincise question. One answer to your problem could be: _enlarge the table element to have more room for the string_ ...

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please read [ask] and [mre] to find out how to ask questions in a way which will lead to people being able to help you more.

Answer (score 1):

You need a non-breaking hyphen. It will then render the entire "2-3" on a new line.

In Aspose this is available through `ControlChar.NonBreakingHyphenChar`, see [documentation](https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words/controlchar/fields/nonbreakinghyphenchar).

Comment: docBuilder.Write("hjfdkshfkjdskjf1.23-3.6,kmdfhksdhfkjsdf1.2-3.6km" + ControlChar.NonBreakingHyphenChar) ; it dosent work for me.

Comment: It is not some magic construct you can slap on any string, you need to replace your regular, breaking hyphens (the `-` in `3-3`) with that non-breaking hyphen character.

Comment: it works for me，the '-' is regular, breaking hyphens i got it.thanks.